# Finite power series how to solve for q

Tags: logarithms, power-series

I'm decent with basic algebra and calculus but I'm having trouble isolating and solving for q in this equation. It seems I've not enough practice with logarithms. The equation is actually for solving for distance given a simple initial velocity and friction coefficient (q) over (f) rendered frames. But Anyway...

Here's the original equation:

---

$$d = V_i \frac{q - q^f}{1-q}$$

What I need is to isolate and solve for **q**.

I 've tried a number of things but I get stuck everytime. The difficulty seems to be in combining **q**.

Someone with a lot of practice at this sort of thing may find this easy :)  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can multiply both sides by the denominator $1-q$, resulting in:

$$d(1-q) = V_i(q-q^f)$$

Rearranging, we obtain

$$V_iq^f - (V_i+d)q + d = 0$$

This is a polynomial equation in $q$, of degree $f$. Polynomials of degree $2$ are quite straightforward to solve, but as the degree increases, so does the difficulty. Polynomials of large degree are best solved by numerical approximation of roots.

In short, depending on the value of $f$, this equation can be quite hard to solve without simply using a computer to obtain an approximate solution. If $f=2$, however, use the quadratic formula!

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful. I was hoping to have a direct formula but this gives me something to work with :)